# Using grep, ls to get a file in bash

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to write a bash script which would locate a single file in the current directory. The file will be used later but I don't need help there. I tried using ls and grep but it doesn't work, I'm a newbie using bash.

```
#!/bin/sh
#Here I need smt like
#trFile = ls | grep myString (but I get file not found error)
echo $trFile
```

Comment: `ls` is not intended to be used this way. Use globbing instead. There's no need to use `grep` with or without `ls`. Globbing will select the set of files your interested in. You can save a glob in an array: `trFile=(*myString*)` or iterate over it directly: `for file in *myString*; do echo "$file"; done`

Comment: [Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  It *will* bite you in the ass, eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
trfile=$( ls | grep myString )
echo $trfile
```

The $( xxx ) causes the commands within to be executed and the output returned.

Comment: *I* know that, but that's a whole 'nother lesson for the OP.  I'm just answering the question as given.  Don't want to overwhelm the poor guy.  We all started somewhere, and we all learned finesse.  Don't discourage the poor thing. {Smile}

Comment: "Don't discourage the poor thing" quite motivating I should say.

Comment: {Grin} I'll help anyone who is willing to try... you're doing great.  Yes, @ghoti has a good point, but you have to use what you know to build up to better things.

Comment: As someone who's had to maintain significant shell scripts written by someone who was only "using what they know", I think it's worth pointing out that there *are* better things so someone doesn't stop learning at "it works for me". ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use shell wildcards, as in

```
ls *${pattern}*
```

And, to store the result in a variable, put it inside a `$()` structure (you can also use deprecated backticks if you like using deprecated functionality that doesn't nest well)

```
var=$( ls *${pattern}* )
```

Or, put your ls | grep in there (but that's bad practice, IMHO):

```
var=$( ls | grep -- "$pattern" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    trFile=`ls | grep "$myString"`
```

In order to run a command and redirect/store its output, you need put the command between backticks. The variable that will store the output, equal sign and the backtick need to be together, as in my example.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if I guess what you're trying to do is, get the capture of the filename from `grep`ping via the output of the `ls` into a shell variable, try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

trFile=`ls | grep "name_of_file"`
echo $trFile
```

Notice the usage of the back-tick operator surrounding the command, what-ever is the output, in this case, will get captured.

Comment: The spaces around the `=` will cause this to break.

Answer (score 0):

using output of ls will bite when you least expect. Better use Globbing. 
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html